# How do I install/make a custom prompt for fish shell?

Tags: linux, shell, crunchbang, fish

I'm using fish 2.0 on Linux, but this might be an installation error, since my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` is empty.

Comment: Which operating system you are using Ubuntu, CentOS, etc etc...?

Comment: @max CrunchBang (#!) C:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`~/.config/fish/config.fish` is empty by default. To create a custom prompt create a file `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish` and fill it with your prompt.

Basic example

```
function fish_prompt
        echo (pwd) '> '
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to save multiple prompts, or add to the list of available prompts that are displayed when you run fish_config?

Answer (score 0):

I make a alternative prompt if starship prompt dosen't exist.

```
# default prompt
function fish_prompt
  echo ''
  set_color cyan; echo (pwd) 
  set_color green; echo '> '
end

# starship prompt
if type -q starship
  starship init fish | source
else
  fish_prompt
end
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
~/.local/share/omf/init.fish

function fish_prompt
        echo (pwd) '> '
end
```

Comment: Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/587724)

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation you feel why it does so. Detail on why and when you should do something with as easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and reedit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: @DavidPostill  I have said the location of the config file that works for me i don't see the same location in any above answers so kindly do not over estimate yourself and do not miss use you reputation.

Comment: The other answer says which is the file to edit to create a custom prompt: ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish.